# How to get image url of image clicked in react

Tags: reactjs, image, url, state

I am using React. I want my user to click on one of four images, then get the url of the image they clicked on. Right now, I am getting a url of the domain, path, and image together with e.target.src (http://localhost:3000/img/cat.png). How can I just get the image url (cat.png)?

Here is part of my code:

```
        this.setState({
            urlClicked: e.target.src
        });
        console.log(this.state.urlClicked)
      }

      <img 
         src={this.state.urlClicked}>
      </img>
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string by "/" and then pop (from the end) the first value:

```js
this.setState({
  urlClick: e.target.src.split("/").pop()
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How could I split it if I want "img/cat.png"?